# Number of iterations Open3D

Tags: kinect, registration, open3d

I'm working with point clouds taken with a Kinect. My goal is the total registration for 3D mapping of places or crops. I'm using the multiway registration code.

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the number of iterations of this code? I've seen that it only does 30 iterations by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of iterations do you mean, the iterations performed by ICP for registration or the iterations performed during global optimization?

You can change the number of iterations for **global optimization** by adjusting the [global optimization convergence criteria](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationConvergenceCriteria.html#open3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationConvergenceCriteria).
Instead of typing

```
o3d.registration.global_optimization(
    pose_graph, o3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationLevenbergMarquardt(),
    o3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationConvergenceCriteria(), option)
```

write

```
o3d.registration.global_optimization(
    pose_graph, o3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationLevenbergMarquardt(),
    o3d.registration.GlobalOptimizationConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration_lm=number_of_iterations), option)
```

For **ICP**, it works in a similar way by adjusting [the ICP convergence criteria](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria.html#open3d.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria):

```
        result_icp = o3d.registration.registration_icp(source, target, 
             max_correspondence_distance_coarse, np.identity(4),
             o3d.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane(),                                  
             o3d.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration=number_of_iterations))
```

Hope this could help!